# Google Calendar colorize weekends in Firefox

Tags: google-calendar, css

I'm currently using the following to colorize weekends in Google Calendar in Firefox (week-view):

```
@-moz-document url-prefix("https://www.google.com/calendar/") {
 td.tg-weekend {
    background-color: #Ffd4d4;}
}
```

But when the day is a weekend, it shows up in the normal bluish color instead of the reddish color. Is it possible to keep the color of the current day red if the current day is a weekend (there is a CSS element called `tg-col-today`, but I don't know how to use that to check if the today column is the same a a weekend column)

Comment: Have a look at this thread: http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/MwuAGn4wVgs
There's a chrome extension in the chrome webstore.

Comment: I'm on Firefox.

Comment: There were pieces of code for FF available.

Comment: I wasn't able to find the source code.

Comment: Also, this isn't what I'm looking for. If 'Today' is Sunday, Sunday gets colored with 'Today's' color instead of Sunday's color, which is the problem I had with the CSS above. I would also prefer a Javascript/CSS solution rather than an add-on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@AdamTaylor answered my question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284675/google-calendar-colorize-weekends-in-firefox)

> Replace `td.tg-weekend` with `td.tg-weekend, td.tg-weekend .tg-today`